# dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIUserNotificationSettings when trying to run on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, swift

I am using Swift. I am trying to ask user for permissions.

I am using this code for asking user permissions:

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil))
```

This code works fine on an iOS8 simulator

But when i try to build and run my app on iPad 2 with iOS7, my app is crashing with the message

> dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIUserNotificationSettings
>     Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/07D5D4BE-E6A3-43EE-ABEB-E9A1E4658F75/MyFirstApp.app/MyFirstApp  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
>    in /var/mobile/Applications/07D5D4BE-E6A3-43EE-ABEB-E9A1E4658F75/MyFirstApp.app/MyFirstApp
>   (lldb)

To ask for user permissions in Obj-C, we use

```
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

but in swift the `application` object has no method named `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`

Any ideas? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

`UIUserNotificationSettings` is available on iOS 8 only. So you have to do something like this:

```
if NSClassFromString("UIUserNotificationSettings") != nil {
    // Do the things in iOS 8 way.
} else {
    // Do the things in iOS 7 way.
}
```

The above code used to crash on iOS 7, but he issue should be fixed in Beta6.

Comment: Yes, I know `UIUserNotificationSettings` is available only in iOS8. How to do it in iOS7 way?

Comment: 'registerForRemoteNotificationTypes' works for me in Swift.

UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(.Badge | .Alert | .Sound)